# JavaScript and wordpress (tried 2 solutions)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem with linking javascript files to wordpress website. I would like to insert this code:

```html
<!--====== Javascripts & Jquery ======-->
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

I tried diffrent methods (adding code in functions.php, adding with a plugin) and none of them worked.

How enter this code correctly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Are you getting any errors on your dev tools console? Also **do not bake in scripts or stylesheets**. You should be using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook to properly manage scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the wp_enqueue_script function like this on your enqueue.php:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
   //add here all the plugins you wish to add
    wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry.js', 'masonry.pkgd.min.js', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main.js', 'main.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script', 100);
```